# Kafka log aggregation and processing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Hi I am trying to use Kafka as a log aggregator and filtering layer so they input into Splunk for eg.

Input side of Kafka will be Kafka S3 connectors and other connectors getting logs from S3 and Amazon Kinesis Data streams.See this pic for reference:

[image]

However what I want to know is inside the Kafka data pipeline for processing or filtering is it necessary to do Spark jobs? Or can that be just done with a simple Kafka streams app and if we have to do this design for several different logs what would be an efficient solution to implement. I am looking at a solution which we can replicate across different log streams without major changes each time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark (or Flink) can essentially replace Kafka Streams and Kafka Connect for transforming topics and writing to S3.

If you want to write directly to Splunk, then there is a Kafka Connector written explicitly for that, and you could use any Kafka client to consume+produce processed data before writing it downstream

Comment: Thx, Kafka connector is just a forward and won't filter or process events based on rules is that right?

Comment: Yes, but you can optionally filter data https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-ak.html